# 303 Error when placing Valence call to input a grade value for a grade item for an individual user

Tags: desire2learn

I am getting a '303 See Other' error when I'm placing a call to provide a specific grade value for a particular user.

```
PUT /d2l/api/le/(D2LVERSION: version)/(D2LID: orgUnitId)/grades/(D2LID: gradeObjectId)/values/(D2LID: userId))
```

All the values are valid (I'd get a 404 error otherwise). Interestingly, the call works for some courses, but not for others. Any ideas?

We've used Fiddler to track the request and the request is in the format (replaced sensitive information with '...'):

```
PUT https://carmen.osu.edu/d2l/api/le/1.0/.../grades/.../values/947067?x_a= ...&x_b=-...&x_d=...&x_c=...&x_t=1374779761 
HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: carmen.osu.edu
Content-Length: 44
Expect: 100-continue

{"GradeObjectType":1,"PointsNumerator":30.0}
```

The response was:

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See other
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 0
Location: /d2l/error/500
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 25 Jul 2013 19:16:40 GMT
```

Edit:  We've discovered that if a grade value is already entered, the above PUT calls works fine. It only gives us a 303 when the grade value is at the default value. This only happens in this course (that we know of).

Comment: Can you please confirm -- when you say "if a grade value is already entered", I am presuming you mean that the grade value was originally entered through the web UI, and not through the API?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like a known issue that the Grades APIs have had in the recent past that I believe has been addressed. The fix for this issue was distributed with the May and June service pack releases. The fixed issue was resolved and described this way:

> Cases which previously permitted dividing by zero in the Valence Learning Framework API for Grades are no longer permitted. This issue was fixed in Learning Suite 10.2 Service Pack 1, Learning Suite 10.1 Service Pack 8, Learning Suite 10 Service Pack 12 and Learning Suite 9.4.1 Service Pack 17.

Please verify that your LMS has been updated to at least the listed service pack level:

- If it has not, then updating to that service pack level may address your issue.
- If updating does not address your issue (or your LMS is already at that patch level), then you should open a support incident with [Desire2Learn's support desk](https://helpdesk.desire2learn.com/), and characterize the incident with them as a possible defect with the LE Assessments components. If you do that, you should also provide the URL to this question on Stack so that the support desk knows you've done some investigation into this issue already.

**Workaround**. There is a workaround for this issue, but it may not be feasible for you, depending upon your use case. If you enter a grade for a user first through the Web UI, then (if this is the known, fixed issue I believe it to be) updating that grade through the APIs should work -- this issue only applied when the first attempt to set a grade value was performed through the API (and, I believe, also only with `Numeric` grade types).